# React native terminal, how to get the process id of new terminal window launched by `react-native start`?

Tags: react-native, terminal, process, zsh

When I run a command like `react-native run-ios` or `react-native start`, it launches a new terminal window with the react native compiling process running/watching inside of the new terminal window.

How can I watch for this new process to start? Or find it among running terminal processes? Find the pid, etc.

My task is specific and obscure, but this is more or less exactly what I need to do. Can anyone help?

Comment: Like, when you end a RN process- it says things like, "Deleting expired sessions ... 4 completed". It knows how to find orphaned RN processes. How?

Answer (score 1):

Checking which PID is used for the port of your react native application should suffice. The standard port for the react-native-cli when running `react-native run-ios` or `react-native start` is 8081. For expo it is 19000.

For specifying a custom port (e.g. 9988) use

```
react-native start --port 9988
```

When your react native application is running, then you can check the corresponding PID in usage for that port (`sudo` might be needed at the beginning of the command)

```
lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep 8081

node      38273 [USER]   31u  IPv6 0x2207bcb724ddd40d      0t0  TCP *:8081 (LISTEN)
```

In this example, the corresponding PID is **38273**

Comment: Is there a way to sort of steal that process and foreground it in another terminal session? Or, my way to control that will probably be, to run `react-native start` before `react-native ios`. Since the react native process normally launched from that second command - will just be used from that first terminal session already running.